# What is the best way to structure the code in this case

Tags: trigger, design-patterns

Sorry for being not quite specific in the title but I find it really hard to describe the scenario in one sentence.

Suppose I have two custom objects: A and B. In the triggers, trigger A calls update B and trigger B also calls trigger A in some scenarios. So to avoid infinite loops, we introduced static variables: Util.isInATrigger and Util.isInBTrigger. And avoid execution of the trigger if the values of those variables are true.

This works for most scenarios, but for one of our major VF page controller, there is a function which runs this:

```
Func myFunc() {
   update A;
   update B;
}
```

So update A actually sets Util.inTriggerA and Util.inTriggerB to be both true. And when running update B, it's not gonna run any triggers.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset `Util.inTriggerA` and `Util.inTriggerB` in between the updates (from the controller):

```
update A;
Util.inTriggerA = false;
Util.inTriggerB = false;
update B;
```

If you wanted, you could make it look prettier by calling `Util.resetTriggerFlags()` or something.

Comment: I am just a little bit wondered that will everything execute in sequence? I mean like: before update A, after update A, Util settings, -> update B

Comment: Yes, it's all synchronous code, so it all executes in sequence.